# From int to char* without strings, and a inconvenient with fstream

Tags: c++, char, int, ofstream

I need help in an "homework". I cant get to work this code because I cant convert from int to *char. The big problem is that I cant use strings. This is the code:

```
//This is in a class

void Interfaz::guardarFCS() {
    char *nombreArchivo = vent.pedirTxt("por favor inserte un nombre para el archivo");
    exportar.setFileName(nombreArchivo,2);
    int ancho = elMapa.getterAncho();
    int alto = elMapa.getterAlto();
    int estadoCasilla;
    int l;
    int k;
    for( l = 0; l<ancho; l++) {
        for( k = 0; k<alto; k++) {
            estadoCasilla = elMapa.casillaMapaInt(l,k);
            if(estadoCasilla==1) {
                exportar.escribir("[");
                exportar.escribir(l);
                exportar.escribir("],[");
                exportar.escribir(k);
                exportar.escribir("]\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where escribir is just an ofstream with `<<whatIsSend`.
in here I cant create a ofstream variable

```
#ifndef Exportador_H
#define Exportador_H

class Exportador {

    //variables
    char fileName[255];
    std::ofstream archivoIn;
public:

    Exportador();
    void setFileName(char*,int);
    void cargar(char*);
    void crear();
    void escribir(char*);
    void guardarFcs(Mapa);
    ~Exportador();

};
#endif
```

the only way to make it work would be to create a new variable for each method since the problem would be using class-declaration for non-member at class scope, if I don't use the std:: another error would arraise called 'ofstream' does not name a type.
either way  for at least reading my code. Any sugestions would be welcome

Comment: very few people on StackOverflow will now what `cargar` or `guardarFcs` mean. I _do_ think `archivoIn` probably should have been named `archivoOut`? In other words: naming matters, and please post English code on SO

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you just need a function to convert an int to a char * without using strings or ostreams? Or is there anything else I am missing? Why the new variable for each method? This is the part, which is not making sense in my opinion. Also you say that `escribir` is just an ostream, but you are using it like a method, so it cannot be. Try to edit your answer for more clarity, maybe then I can help.

Comment: Your question is confusing, I don't get what the actual problem is. It might help if you **edit** the question so to make it clear. Changing spanish names into english for the code would be a plus, since it will be easier for non-spanish speakers to understand your code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully see what you are asking, but this should work:

```
void Exportador::escribir(int i)
{
     char convertedToText[10] = {0};
     // convert to text, this is the exericse 
     //   (use 
     //       - while loop, 
     //       - i=i/10 and 
     //       - i%10)
     // don't forget to null-terminate

     archivoIn << convertedToText;
}
```

I'm not showing you the actual conversion (hint: `itoa` might be what you want if you're allowed to use it), as that would remove the exercise from the homework

Comment: `archivoIn << i` works just fine if `archiveIn` is `ofstream`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I thought the conversion is homework. I agree it isn't clear. Anyways...